# I am trying to send a request from anroid emulator. But the application is not giving proper output and breaking on client.sendasync

Tags: xamarin.forms.listview

```
{ 
   var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
   {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",password),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","password")
   };

   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost(delibirately written)/Token");
   request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

   var client = new HttpClient();
   var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
   var jwt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jwt);

   var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");
   var accessExpires = jwtDynamic.Value<DateTime>(".expires");
   Settings.AccessTokenExpiration = accessExpires;

   Debug.WriteLine(jwt);

   return accessToken;
}
```

I was getting exception first and then i used try catch and then i found out that application is breaking at client.async.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Comment: Look at the exception details and InnerException to find out what error occurred.